# Pagefile is active even when RAM usage is below 70%. How do I fix it?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, pagefile

I have this laptop with decent specs:

CPU: Intel i5-8250u 4 cores (8 threads) @ 1.60GHz / Max Turbo @ 3.4GHz

GPU: Integrated Intel UHD 620 + discrete Radeon 520 GDDR5

RAM: 4GB DDR4 2400MHz

HDD: 1TB Toshiba mq01abd100 5400rpm

The only problem I have with this laptop is pagefile being actively working all the time making my applications load slower than they should. My RAM usage is always below 80%. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Look in Task Manager which application is using too much memory.

Comment: @harrymc it is Google Chrome at 500MB/s~, next is Windows Security at 100MB/s. the rest is below 100MB/s.

Comment: What makes you think applications using a page file make them slower?  A page file is designed to make them faster otherwise Windows has to perform operations to free up memory for the application immediately.

Comment: That's normal. The culprits are small amount of RAM and slow HDD. I'm not sure if you can tell Windows to page less - it's doing so to use more RAM for apps that need it and cache, actually speeding up the system.

Comment: Yet 80% is pretty full. Have you installed any memory optimizing product such as Process Lasso? If not, adding RAM is the only solution. 4GB is nowadays counted as too small.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm skeptical about my HDD performance. It's quite slow to my liking. I'm not sure whether Windows 10 is so demanding because loading applications for me take like 10-30 seconds, and for games it's over 45+ secs.

Comment: @gronostaj you think my RAM and/or HDD specs are slow? Do you think if I switch to SSD my problem will be immediately fixed even if RAM is 4GB?

Comment: Windows will start paging at approximately 50% RAM usage. With only 4GB RAM, that's pretty much straight away, once the OS is fully loaded. That's simply how it works. I have no idea who made that decision or why, nor whether you can change it.

Comment: @liyan - Your page file is still making those operations faster not slower.  You have a slow (vase frequency) mobile processor, an incredibly small amount of memory, likely trying to run applications that your machine barely meet the minimum requirements for so a half minute load time is to be expected.  Your system would benefit from more memory more than likely.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for the answer.

Comment: The mobile CPU shouldn't be that much of an issue. Difference will be noticeable compared to CPUs not optimized for power conservation, but it should still have plenty of power to run day-to-day apps. I'd start with a RAM upgrade if possible, that's your main bottleneck right now and other upgrades won't make a tremendous difference without this. Going for an SSD is always a good idea, but a 1 TB one will be pricey - consider sacrificing some disk space.

Comment: Those are NOT decent specs. 8 GB of RAM is a minimum to get decent performance in Windows 10 with a SSD. With a 5400 rpm disk you need 16 GB and still it will feel slow until you get a SSD. I know Microsoft says 2 GB of RAM is enough for W10. If you define "it will boot" as "enough" that is true. 4 GB is usable with a light workload (Office and a web-browser with a couple of tabs). Anything above that and you need 8 GB RAM as minimum. And a U type CPU (which throttles back heavily for powersaving) isn't really helping either, unless you run it in high-performance power-mode continuously.

Answer (score 4):

This is normal.

At 70% memory usage I would expect there to be pagefile usage, and in fact much earlier than that. If the pagefile were not use the memory manager would have to resort to other ways to obtain memory and performance would suffer.

70% memory usage does not mean 30% is free and unused. Most of this is actually in use, it is just a different kind of usage. It is a kind of cache that isn't in active use but still contains potentially useful data. Experience over the years has shown that this memory is a major contributor to good performance. This memory is still immediately available to any application that needs it. If the memory gauge showed full memory usage it would show over 90% most of the time and would be neither useful not interesting, and thus useless.

The memory manager always tries to maintain a reasonable balance between in use and available memory. When memory pressure is low the memory manager will permit applications to use pretty much whatever they want. This is good. But when the demand for memory increases the memory manager will use more active measures to maintain available memory. Part of this is saving data that has not been recently accessed to the pagefile. Initially the data remains in memory but can be discarded if the memory is needed for other purposes. Saving data to the pagefile is near free in terms of performance. It requires very little CPU time and since other activities can occur at the same time there is no need to wait for the procedure to complete.

As memory demand rises the memory manager must become more aggressive in maintaining available memory. More data is written to the pagefile and read back as needed. Executable code from EXE and DLL files is dropped from memory and later read back in to memory. Nearing 100% usage the memory managers options are very limited. At this point even recently accessed memory must be reassigned to other purposes and performance becomes painfully slow. This is not a good situation but simply the memory manager making the best of a bad situation. It is doing what is necessary to keep the system running.

This is all very complex. It is the result of decades of research, development, and testing and for companies like Microsoft and Apple has cost a great deal of money. Trust the memory manager to do the right thing, even when you do not understand.

Comment: Additionally data (that does not change frequently) can be written to the page file while the original data is still kept in RAM so in case later if more RAM is needed the data can simply be dropped from RAM as it is already present in page file.